# how to get the previous 3 months with the current month in php

Tags: php, date

How to get the previous 3 months with the current month in php?

Comment: current month - 1, current month - 2 ,current month - 3 this is the base logic now tell what is the format of month?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")); //it's 00:00 first day of current month
mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-1); //it's 00:00 first day of previous month
mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-2); //it's 00:00 first day 2 month before 
mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-3); //it's 00:00 first day 3 month before
```

This functions return unix timestamp, and can be formated with date function.

You will need to read about functions: [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), [mktime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by appyling the string-to-time method of PHP

```
$lastMonth = date('m', strtotime('last month'));
$twoMonthsAgo = date('m', strtotime('-2 months'));
$threeMonthsAgo = date('m', strtotime('-3 months'));
```

You can read more about strtotime here: http://www.php.net/strtotime